# Cleaning Arrays of Arrays which consist of nils

Tags: arrays, ruby, null, data-cleaning

For example I have an array:

```
[[nil, nil], [1, 2], [nil, nil], [nil, nil]]
```

What is the best way to clean it? Array must have only arrays which do not consist of nil. After cleaning it has to be:

```
[[1,2]]
```

Something like:

```
[[nil, nil], [1, 2], [nil, nil], [nil, nil]].each {|x| x - [nil]}
```

Comment: What about a sub-array `[1,2,nil,3]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The methods on arrays that remove `nil` elements is called [compact](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-compact). However, that is not quite enough for this situation because you have an array of arrays. In addition you will want to [select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select) the non-nil arrays, or [reject](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-reject) the arrays that are `nil`. You can easily combine the two in the following way:

`[[nil, nil], [1, 2], [nil, nil], [nil, nil]].reject { |arr| arr.compact.empty? }`

This will only work if you have sub arrays of numbers OR `nil`s. If your sub arrays contain both e.g. `[1, nil, 2]`, then this solution will keep the entire sub array.

It is possible to mutate the sub array to remove `nil` while you iterate over the sub arrays, but it can be considered practice to mutate while you iterate. Nevertheless, the way to do this would be to use the *bang* version of the `compact` method which mutates the original object:

`.reject { |arr| arr.compact!.empty? }`

This will take `[[1, 2, nil, 3]]` and return `[[1, 2, 3]]`.

As sagarpandya82 pointed out, you can also use the [all](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) or [any?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-any-3F) methods for simply checking if everything is `nil`, or if anything is `nil` instead of removing the `nil`s.

To recap:

```
original_array = [[nil, nil],[1, nil, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
original_array.reject { |arr| arr.all?(:nil) } # returns [[1, nil, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
original_array.reject { |arr| arr.compact.empty? } # returns [[1, nil, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
original_array.reject { |arr| arr.any?(:nil) } # returns [[1, 2, 3]]
original_array.reject { |arr| arr.compact!.empty? } # returns [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2]]
```

Comment: it's be nice to see a recursive way of doing this, though

Comment: It sounded like OP wanted a method chaining solution, but a recursive solution is definitely doable with a method call.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're only interested in 2D-Arrays then:

Rid sub-arrays consisting of only `nil`s:

```
arr.reject { |arr| arr.all?(&:nil?) }
```

Rid sub-arrays consisting of any `nil`s:

```
arr.reject { |arr| arr.any?(&:nil?) }
```

Answer (score 3):

- `compact` will remove `nil` elements from an array.
- `map` will run over each item in an array and return a fresh array by applying code on the item of the array. Note that in your example *elements of the array* are itself ... Arrays.
- `reject` will return a new array without the elements that your given code answers 'false' to.
- `select` will return a new array with the elements that your given code 'likes' (kinda opposite of reject).

So if you just want to **remove all `nil`s** from an array and its subarray (but not sub-subarrays), you could call

```
list = [[1,2], [nil], [1,nil,2]]
list.map(&:compact).reject(&:empty?) #=> [[1,2], [1,2]]
```

which is the same as

```
compacted_list = list.map do |element|
  element.compact
end
non_empty_list = compacted_list.reject do |element|
  element.empty?
end
```

If you want to **remove all `[nil, nil]` entries** from the list/array

```
list.reject{|element| element == [nil, nil]}
```

or if it is more about selecting the non-nil elements (this is really just about intent-revealing code)

```
list.select{|element| element != [nil, nil])
```

Most of these functions have an `!` counterpart (like `reject!`) which does the modification *in place*, which means you do not have to assign the return value (like in `new_list = old_list.reject()`).

Answer (score 3):

There appear to be differing interpretations of the question.

If, as suggested by the question's example, all elements (arrays) that contain one `nil` contain only `nil`s, and those elements are to be excluded, this would do that:

```
[[nil, nil], [1, 2], [nil, nil], [nil, nil]].select(&:first)
  #=> [!1, 2]]
```

If all elements that contain at least one `nil` are to be excluded, this would do that:

```
[[3, nil], [1, 2], [3, 4, 5, nil]].reject { |a| a.any?(&:nil?) }
  #=> [!1, 2]]
```

If all `nil`s are to be removed from each element, this would do that:

```
[[3, nil], [1, 2], [nil], [nil, 3, 4]].map(&:compact)
  #=> [[3], [1, 2], [], [3, 4]]
```

If all `nil`s are to be removed from each element, and then all empty arrays are to be removed, this would do that:

```
[[3, nil], [1, 2], [nil], [nil, 3, 4]].map(&:compact).reject(&:empty?)
  #=> [[3], [1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: what does `&:first` do? :)

Comment: @SunilD., this is effectively the same as `arr.select { |pair| pair.first }`. `pair.first` is truthy if it equals neither `nil` nor `false`. Hence, an element `[a,b]` is selected if `a` is truthy. I assume from the example in the question that `b` is `nil` if and only if `a` is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

I was recently looking at [facets](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets), a ruby gem that provides a lot of core ruby language extensions.

One of the examples they give is for the [Array#recurse](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rubyworks/facets/Array%3Arecurse) method, I'll show it below:

```
arr = ["a", ["b", "c", nil], nil]
arr.recurse{ |a| a.compact! }
#=> ["a", ["b", "c"]]
```

This gets about half the job done in your case - you also want to remove non empty arrays.

Facets works by patching core Ruby methods. That means as soon as you run `require 'facets/array/recurse'`, any previously defined `Array#recurse` method will be overridden. Patching core methods is generally ill-advised because of the possibility of naming conflicts.

Still, it's a useful method, and it's easy to define it in such a way that it takes an array as an argument instead of operating on the value of `self`. You can then use it to define two methods which together fulfill your purpose:

```
module ArrayUtils
  def recurse(array, *types, &block)
    types = [array.class] if types.empty?
    a = array.reduce([]) do |arr, value|
      case value
      when *types
        arr << recurse(value, *types, &block)
      else
        arr << value
      end
      arr
    end
    yield a
  end

  def recursive_compact(array)
    recurse(array, &:compact)
  end

  def recursive_remove_nonempty(array)
    recurse(array) do |arr|
      arr.reject do |x|
        x.is_a?(Array) && x.empty?
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Testing it out:

```
include ArrayUtils

orig = [[nil, nil], [1, 2], [nil, nil], [nil, nil]]
compacted = recursive_compact(orig)
nonempties = recursive_remove_nonempty compacted

puts "original: #{orig.inspect}"
puts "compacted: #{compacted.inspect}"
puts "nonempties: #{nonempties.inspect}"
```

and running

```
original: [[nil, nil], [1, 2], [nil, nil], [nil, nil]]
compacted: [[], [1, 2], [], []]
nonempties: [[1, 2]]
```